# How do I specify the ECMAScript version target of my Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm developing a brand new VUE application and want to use the latest ES features like `??` etc.

I have turned on the following settings in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  },
```

But the build error tells me `Syntax Error: Unexpected token`,
I guess it's an error somewhere (babel?), but I searched the internet and don't see the problem, how do I upgrade my ES version?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vuetify-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "lint:fix": "vue-cli-service lint --fix"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,vue}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^1.2.1",
    "@vue/babel-preset-jsx": "^1.2.4",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "swrv": "^0.8.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us a list of your dev dependencies?

Comment: @NoReply I add my dev deps list, thanks your review!

Comment: I checked the list of issues and feature descriptions about vue/cli and I found that I can use es features in the <script> area, but I can't use them in the vue <template>, e.g. {{ data ?? '123' }}.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the necessary plugin via npm:

   npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator
2. Add the plugin to your babel.rc:

   "plugins": [..., "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"]

You should now be able to use the Nullish Coalescing operator within your project.

Comment: It didn't work, so I checked the vuejs/vue-cli repo issues and found that it seems to be due to a webpack v4 issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5881